# spark yarn: Too many containers asked

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I got the following error:

```
2019-02-01 12:01:39 INFO  YarnAllocator:54 - Driver requested a total number of 2007 executor(s).
2019-02-01 12:01:39 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:54 - Requesting 968 new executors because tasks are backlogged (new desired total will be 2007)
2019-02-01 12:01:39 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:54 - New executor 25 has registered (new total is 26)
2019-02-01 12:01:39 WARN  ApplicationMaster:87 - Reporter thread fails 1 time(s) in a row.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException: Too many containers asked, 1365198
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMServerUtils.normalizeAndValidateRequests(RMServerUtils.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService.allocate(ApplicationMasterService.java:511)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:60)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationMasterProtocol$ApplicationMasterProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationMasterProtocol.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2202)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.allocate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.AMRMClientImpl.allocate(AMRMClientImpl.java:277)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator.allocateResources(YarnAllocator.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:556)
```

How to debug/fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check Dynamic Resource Allocation is ENABLED,

spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled = true

this will use as many as it can depends up on the system rescue availability, this may be causing the problem.

On the other note, this behaviour can be controlled by setting the

spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors =

please note that, driver also allocated some of the containers. you need to manage the memory allocations for Executors and drivers.